# Javascript change array's order

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to change an array in the following order:

So I have the following array:

`const weekDaysArray = ['Mo', 'Tu', 'We', 'Th', 'Fr', 'Sa', 'Su'];` which contains the days of the week in order, then I get a variable

`const firstWeekday = Object.values(formattedReadsByDay)[0].dayOfWeek;` which will return a day of the week, let's say `We` for the case.

So when this returns `We` i would like to change the array to:

`weekDaysArray = ['We', 'Th', 'Fr', 'Sa', 'Su', 'Mo', 'Tu'];`

I tried `weekDaysArray [...weekDays.slice(-1), ...weekDays.slice(0, -1)]` this but it doesn't work. Any ideeas?

Comment: There is a typo in your code? I don't see the `weekDays` variable where is defined. Should it be `weekDaysArray`?

Comment: No. You can ignore those, it was just an example where i'm slicing. The two variables i care about are firstWeekDay and weekDaysArray

Comment: Ok, in this case you should provide a more accurate example of your code and maybe what's te result you have: is it a js error? Is an array with wrong length? Is an array with correct length but wrong order?...

Comment: `[...weekDays.slice(2), ...weekDays.slice(0,2)]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to:

1. Find the index of the first day.
2. Get the part of the array *from* the first day (inclusive) to the end. This is the new start part of the week.
3. Get the part of the array from the beginning *to* the first day (exclusive). This is the new end part of the week.
4. Join the two parts.

This can be achieved like this:

```js
const weekDaysArray = ['Mo', 'Tu', 'We', 'Th', 'Fr', 'Sa', 'Su'];

const firstWeekday = "We";

//1. find index
const index = weekDaysArray.indexOf(firstWeekday);

//2. get start of the week
const startWeek = weekDaysArray.slice(index);
//3. get end of the week
const endWeek = weekDaysArray.slice(0, index);

//4. combine the new week
const result = [...startWeek, ...endWeek];

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks. This one is super clean.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `weekDaysArray.push(weekDaysArray.shift())`
That will move the first item of array to end.
Like this `[1, 2, 3] -> [ 2, 3, 1]`
Then you need to check if `weekDaysArray[0] == your day`, you will return array. If no, do the same operation one more time.

Answer (score 1):

An implementation of what [Dima Vak answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61935447/4754538) could be something like:

```js
function getOrderedWeek (firstWeekDay) {
    const weekDaysArray = ['Mo', 'Tu', 'We', 'Th', 'Fr', 'Sa', 'Su'];

    for(let i = 0; i < weekDaysArray.length; i++) {
        if (weekDaysArray[0] === firstWeekDay) break;
        weekDaysArray.push(weekDaysArray.shift())
    }

    return weekDaysArray;
}

const firstWeekday = Object.values(formattedReadsByDay)[0].dayOfWeek;
console.log({
    result: getOrderedWeek(firstWeekday)
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.